# Browser page goes blank when item tile is dropped or shuffled: react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

Please help! I have been on this for days. The item tile can be dragged, But immediately after dropping the tile, the browser page goes blank followed by the error below in the console. (I have commented out `React.StrictMode`).

[The error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRZrg.png)

The item tiles are not draggable at all with `React.StrictMode` enabled. The console error when I click on the tile when `React.StrictMode` is enabled is below:

[console error caused by attempted dragging with `React.StrictMode` enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHGCY.png)

**scrumboard.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './scrumboard.css';
import data from '../../static/data.js';
import Tasks from '../tasks/tasks.jsx';

export class Scrumboard extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: data,
            isOpen: false,
            tasks: null
        }
    }

    openModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: true
        })
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        })
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            tasks: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        })
    }

  render() {
    console.log("Logged in as ", data.fullname);
    return (
      <div className='scrumboard'>
        <nav>
            <h1>CHATSCRUM</h1>
            <div className="var">
                <p>User type: { data.usertype }</p>
                <p>Project Name: { data.projectname }</p>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <p id="info">Hello { data.fullname }. Welcome to your Scrumboard</p>

        <Tasks />

        <div id="modal" className={this.state.isOpen ? "show" : "hidden"}>
            <div className="header">
                <h3>Add a new task</h3>
                <h3 id="close" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>X</h3>
            </div>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input id="inp" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button>CONFIRM</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <button className="add" onClick={() => this.openModal()}>ADD TASK</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Scrumboard
```

**tasks.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./tasks.css";
import tasks from "../../static/tasks.js";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

export default function Tasks() {

    const [weeklyTasks, setWeeklyTasks] = useState(tasks);

    const [dailyTasks, setDailyTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setWeeklyTasks(tasks)
    }, [tasks]);

    const handleOnDragEnd = result => {
        const { source, destination } = result
        if (!destination) return;
        if (source.droppableId === destination.droppableId) {

            if (source.droppableId === "weeklyTasks") {
                let tempWeeklyTasks = Array.from(weeklyTasks)
                const [reorderedItem] = tempWeeklyTasks.splice(source.index, 1);
                 tempWeeklyTasks.splice(destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
                setWeeklyTasks(tempWeeklyTasks)
            } else {
                let tempDailyTasks = Array.from(dailyTasks)
                const [reorderedItem] = tempDailyTasks.splice(source.index, 1);
                 tempDailyTasks.splice(destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
                setDailyTasks(tempDailyTasks)
            }

        } else {
            let tempWeeklyTasks = weeklyTasks;
            let tempDailyTasks = dailyTasks;
    
            if (source.droppableId === "weeklyTasks") {
                const [removed] = tempWeeklyTasks.splice(source.index, 1)
                tempDailyTasks.splice(destination.index, 0, removed)
                setWeeklyTasks(tempWeeklyTasks)
                setDailyTasks(tempDailyTasks)
            } else {
                const [removed] = tempDailyTasks.splice(source.index, 1);
                tempWeeklyTasks.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
                setWeeklyTasks(tempWeeklyTasks);
                setDailyTasks(tempDailyTasks);
            }
        }
    }

    return (
    <div className="tasker">
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
            <div className="container">
                <Droppable droppableId="tasket">
                    {(provided) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="weekly-box" {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                                <h3>Weekly Tasks</h3>
                                {weeklyTasks.map(({id, item}, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Draggable draggableId={id.toString()} key={id} index={index}>
                                            {(provided) => (
                                                <p className="task" {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                                                    {item}
                                                </p>
                                            )}
                                        </Draggable>
                                    )
                                })}
                                {provided.placeholder}
                            </div>
                        )
                    }}
                </Droppable>

                <Droppable droppableId="tasketer">
                    {(provided) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="daily-box" {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                                <h3>Daily Targets</h3>
                                {dailyTasks.map(({id, item}, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Draggable draggableId={id.toString()} key={id} index={index}>
                                            {(provided) => (
                                                <p className="task" {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                                                    {item}
                                                </p>
                                            )}
                                        </Draggable>
                                    )
                                })}
                                {provided.placeholder}
                            </div>
                        )
                    }}
                </Droppable>
            </div>
        </DragDropContext>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**data.js**

```
const data = {
    fullname: "Scientist Samir",
    usertype: "Developer",
    projectname: "ChatScrum"
}

export default data;
```

**tasks.js**

```
const tasks = [
    {id: 1, item: "build chatscrum"},
    {id: 2, item: "build trello"},
    {id: 3, item: "go swimming"},
    {id: 4, item: "play Call of Duty"},
    {id: 5, item: "Sleep all day"}
]

export default tasks;
```

Thank you :)

Comment: On the first render weeklyTasks list will be undefined, try using {weeklyTasks?.map(({id, item}, index) => { ...} ? will make sure that map is called once weeklyTasks are there in memory

Comment: @AsadAshraf Same error bro.

Comment: @AsadAshraf ; Fixed. Later discovered that it was a conflict the droppableId. Thank you for your help.

Comment: good, nicely done